# UNICODE_STRING to Null terminated

Tags: c, windows, string, unicode, utf-16

I need to convert a UNICODE_STRING structure to a simple NULL TERMINATED STRING.

```
typedef 
struct _UNICODE_STRING 
{
    USHORT  Length;  
    USHORT  MaximumLength;  
    PWSTR   Buffer;
} 
UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;
```

I can't find a clean sollution on MSDN about it.
Anyone been there?
I am not using .net so I need a native API sollution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say "NULL TERMINATED STRING" do you mean a null terminated wchar_t string or a null terminated ASCII/Multi-byte character string?

Answer (score 4):

You should use WideCharToMultiByte. As an estimate for the output buffer size, you can use the Length field - but do consider the case of true multi-byte strings, in which case it will fail with ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER, and you need to start over with a larger buffer. Or, you call it with an output buffer size of 0 first always, so it tells you the necessary size of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling for unicode and converting to ansi, this appears to work for me
(Modified from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138813):

```
HRESULT UnicodeToAnsi(LPCOLESTR pszW, LPSTR* ppszA){
    ULONG cbAnsi, cCharacters;
    DWORD dwError;
    // If input is null then just return the same.    
    if (pszW == NULL)    
    {
        *ppszA = NULL;
        return NOERROR;
    }
    cCharacters = wcslen(pszW)+1;
    cbAnsi = cCharacters*2;

    *ppszA = (LPSTR) CoTaskMemAlloc(cbAnsi);
    if (NULL == *ppszA)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    if (0 == WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pszW, cCharacters, *ppszA, cbAnsi, NULL, NULL)) 
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        CoTaskMemFree(*ppszA);
        *ppszA = NULL;
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
    }
    return NOERROR;
}
```

Usage:

```
LPSTR pszstrA;
UnicodeToAnsi(my_unicode_string.Buffer, &pszstrA);
cout << "My ansi string: (" << pszstrA << ")\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not say whether you need an ANSI or UNICODE null-terminated string, I'm going to assume UNICODE:

```
#include <string>

UNICODE_STRING us;
// fill us as needed...

std::wstring ws(us.Buffer, us.Length);
// use ws.c_str() where needed...
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative code that converts to ANSI and does not require number of unicode characters in UNICODE_STRING that has to be passed as a parameter to WideCharToMultiByte. (Note that UNICODE_STRING.Length is a number of bytes, not unicode characters, and wcslen does not work if buffer is not zero-terminated).

```
UNICODE_STRING tmp;
// ...
STRING dest; // or ANSI_STRING in kernel mode

LONG (WINAPI *RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString)(PVOID, PVOID, BOOL);
*(FARPROC *)&RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString = 
    GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("NTDLL.DLL"), "RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString");
if(!RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString)
{
    return;
}

ULONG unicodeBufferSize = tmp.Length;
dest.Buffer = (PCHAR)malloc(unicodeBufferSize+1); // that must be enough...
dest.Length = 0;
dest.MaximumLength = unicodeBufferSize+1;

RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString(&dest, &tmp, FALSE);
dest.Buffer[dest.Length] = 0; // now we get it in dest.Buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WCHAR* UnicodeStringToNulTerminated(UNICODE_STRING* str)
{
  WCHAR* result;
  if(str == NULL)
    return NULL;
  result = (WCHAR*)malloc(str->Length + 2);
  if(result == NULL)
    // raise?
    return NULL;
  memcpy(result, str->Buffer, str->Length);
  result[str->Length] = L'\0';
  return result;
}
```

Comment: 'result->Length' should be 'str->Length'.